# iis7 php upload big files

Tags: php, iis-7, file-upload

Environmet: iis7 + php

I need to upload very big files, 3 GB maximum...

to allow 3GB upload files in iis7:
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config

```
...
<requestfiltering> 
...
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3145728000" />
...
</requestfiltering> 
...
```

if i put in php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 3000M
upload_max_filesize = 3000M
```

the login form doesn't work...

and i only put it in upload script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
$upload_max_filesize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');

ini_set('post_max_size', '2901M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2900M');

...

ini_set('post_max_size', $post_max_size);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', $upload_max_filesize);
```

but doesn't work... i don't know how to fix this problem :(

Comment: i would think ftp would be better than http for such large files

Answer (score 1):

i fix it putting the memory limit bigger than post_max_size and post_max_size bigger than upload_max_filesize in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 4001M
post_max_size = 3001M
upload_max_filesize = 3000M
```

thanks for Awea

Answer (score 0):

You need to set :

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time
```

Too but Dagon have right ftp would be better for big files upload

**EDIT**

Asynchronous upload : [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

Comment: what's happen ? Details plz :p

Comment: i put the timeout to 0 and CGI timeout to 23:59:59 and 3 minutes and 30 seconds later browser puts DONE, $_FILES empty :(

Comment: can you add your html and your script ?

Comment: may be you was more lucky with an asynchronously upload, check the link in my post

Comment: the problem is in: 
ini_set('post_max_size', '2901M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2900M');
changing this params in script doesn't work, only works changing in php.ini but if i change this params i can't logging in the system, i'm going to open new post in stackoveflow, thank you very much

Comment: don't create a copiy of this post :)

Comment: i fix it putting the memory limit bigger than post_max_size and post_max_size bigger than upload_max_filesize in php.ini

memory_limit = 4001M 
post_max_size = 3001M
upload_max_filesize = 3000M

thanks for all